# C++ - Pointer to a class method

Tags: c++, detours

I have to set up a pointer to a library function (`IHTMLDocument2::write`) which is a method of the class `IHTMLDocument2`. (for the curious: i have to hook that function with Detours)

I can't do this directly, because of type mismatch, neither can I use a cast (`reinterpret_cast<>` which is the "right one" afaik doesn't work)

Here's what I am doing:

```
HRESULT (WINAPI *Real_IHTMLDocument2_write)(SAFEARRAY *) = &IHTMLDocument2::write
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: it has been my experience that in order to point to a class method, said method must be static.

Comment: @San Jacinto. That's not true. You can have pointers to normal methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pointer to function has the following type:

```
HRESULT (WINAPI IHTMLDocument2::*)(SAFEARRAY*)
```

As you can see, it's qualified with it's class name. It requires an instance of a class to call on (because it is not a static function):

```
typedef HRESULT (WINAPI IHTMLDocument2::*DocumentWriter)(SAFEARRAY*);

DocumentWriter writeFunction = &IHTMLDocument2::write;

IHTMLDocument2 someDocument = /* Get an instance */;
IHTMLDocument2 *someDocumentPointer = /* Get an instance */;

(someDocument.*writefunction)(/* blah */);
(someDocumentPointer->*writefunction)(/* blah */);
```

Comment: OK... Works right... THank you very much!

Now I have to create a new function whose type is:

HRESULT (WINAPI IHTMLDocument2::*)(SAFEARRAY*)

is this possible from outside the class?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a [member function pointer](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html).  A normal function pointer won't work, because when you call a (non-static) class member function there is an implicit `this` pointer referring to an instance of the class.

Comment: +1 for solving my commented problem... but makes me cringe at c++ for introducing another syntax item to learn. what is the point of it? to guarantee encapsulation safety?

Comment: Member function pointers aren't used that often it seems, but they do have their uses.  For example, boost::bind takes advantage of member function pointers so you can do, for example boost::bind(&Foo::somefunction, &instance, arg1, arg2)

Comment: @San:  Member function pointers (MFP's) are handled differently from normal functions pointers because they *ARE* different... it's not just syntactic sugar.  The size of MFP's are often larger (8 or 12 bytes vs 4 on 32-bit machines), they pass an implicit this pointer, often they call through a small chunk of thunking code rather than directly (so they can possibly invoke virtual functions).  So they are both more expensive memory-wise and for CPU-performance (cost to invoke) than a normal function pointer.

Comment: They can be particularly useful as callback handlers.  Plus, the annoying syntax can be mitigated by using boost::mem_fn or boost::bind.